# IE error with .options.length=0; or .setProperty('selected','selected')?

Tags: php, javascript, mootools

Internet Explorer 8 and 7 fails with error when i update the select box with new option and choose the selected option. In other browsers this works fine and without errors. I use Mootools 1.2.3.

```
<?php
    $getdestiny=$_GET['dest'];
    $getcountry=$_GET['countr'];

    print "<script type='text/javascript'>
        window.addEvent('domready', function() {

       var countrh=$getcountry;
       var desth=$getdestiny;

       if (countrh==4){
             $('destination').options.length=0; //error fails here   
             var opt0 = $('destination').options[0] = new Option('Сhoose Destination',0);
             var opt1 = $('destination').options[1] = new Option('London-Aberdeen','1');

              var len = $('destination').options.length;
              if (desth < len){
             opt$getdestiny.setProperty('selected','selected'); //or here

        else {
        //do nothing
        }
    });
    </script>"
```

Can it be because i use double-assignment for vars opt* or what can it be else? Advise me please.

Comment: UPD. Error message is "Object doesn't support this property or method" code:0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just have a syntax error here where you're getting your 2nd error at.

```
if (desth < len){
   opt$getdestiny.setProperty('selected','selected'); //or here
else {
  //do nothing
}
```

is missing a closing } for the first part of the if statement.  Should be like this:

```
if (desth &lt; len){
   opt$getdestiny.setProperty('selected','selected'); //or here
}else {
  //do nothing
}
```

**ADDENDUM:**

Ok your problem is that you're trying to use a MooTools function on an element that's not wrapped in MooTools.  You can fix this by wrapping it in a $() function like this:

```
$(opt$getdestiny).set('selected','selected');
```

I also typically just set selected = true so you can try that as well. Make sure to use true, not the string 'true'.

Comment: I updated my Answer post with more details, this should clear up the problem you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

In the past we have used the following syntax successfully to mark a select option element as "selected":

```
option.selected = true;
```

Comment: opt$getdestiny.option.selected = true; gives an error Message: 'option' -  is null or not an object

Comment: function removeAllOptions(el) {
  var el=$(el);
        if(el.get('tag')!='select') return el;  
        for(var i=el.options.lelngth-1;i>=0;i--) el.remove(i);  
        return el; 
  }

same thing...

Comment: I'm not too familiar with PHP.. but I'm assuming "opt$getdestiny" is the option element?  In that case wouldn't it be "opt$getdestiny.selected = true;"?

Comment: Also, to get the number of options in a select, instead of "el.options.length" do "el.length".

Answer (score 0):

in mootools 1.2, setProperty() got deprecated. the prototype is now just element.set(prop, value); - one setter and one getter (element.get()) for anything :)